# How do I make Touch-Up-Inside only fire on actual touch-up-inside in the correct control?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a matrix of 3X3 UIbuttons, and I want to allow the user to drag his finger and fire the correct event based on where the finger *leaves* the touch panel.

Currently, the touch-up-inside will only fire for a button if the finger touched down in that button.

What is the easiest way to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's going to depend on whether or not you want the buttons to do *other things* besides this touch up behavior. I'll assume you do want this.

The most flexible behavior would probably come from a gesture recognizer attached to the buttons' superview. All you need is a few lines to set it up and a single method to interpret it, so it's easy enough to drop in or remove if you go a different way later.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDrag:)];

recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //So the user can still interact with controls in the modal view
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```

So now we've configured the recognizer. How do we handle it?

```
- (void)handleDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    //We care only about touching *up*, so let's not bother checking until the gesture ends

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];

        //Iterate through your button collection

        for (UIButton *button in self.buttons)
        {

            //Let's test to see if the point is inside this button
            if (![button pointInside:[button convertPoint:location fromView:self.view] withEvent:nil]) 
            {
                //Do your thing
                [self userTouchedUpOnButtonWithIndex:button.tag] //For example
                //or
                [self userTouchedUpOnButtonWithIndex:[self.buttons indexOfObject:button]];

                break;
            }
        }
}
```

Easy enough?

Answer (score 1):

parentView is size 3x3 with 9 buttons of size 1x1 each as subviews.  parentView is firstResponder.  parentView handles all touch events. parentView's UIController determines which button will respond.

Comment: This is an approach I've been considering myself. Sounds easy enough, too.